# Activity View Indicator isn't animating at LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, launch-screen

I want to use Activity View Indicator on my app while it's loading, so I have LaunchScreen.storyboard.
I use "Behaviour - Animating" on my AVI, but it is not animating.
When I use Act.V.Indic. not in LaunchScreen - it is animating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LaunchScreen storyboard is static. iOS actually creates an image from the LaunchScreen and displays that image. It is impossible to have any dynamic or animated content in a LaunchScreen storyboard.

If your app takes time to load, then your app should display another screen as soon as it starts and that screen should show the activity indicator view.

Answer (score 0):

Launch screens are static. Even though you set it to animating, it won't animate, simply because it can't. Think of them as outlines for your launch images. iOS will generate an image from them, that'll be shown to the user. They are a more convenient way of generating launch screens but aren't interactive or dynamic.