# Activity Indicator in LaunchScreen.storyboard is not spinning. ( IOS LaunchScreen Problem )

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I added an Activity Indicator in IOS LaunchScreen.storyboard. It is showing but the indicator is not spinning. I had ticked the animating under behavior, but still, the indicator is not spinning.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43545215/5443937

Answer (score 0):

You cant add ani animations to launch screen
in last iOS version app launched pretty fast
try use LaunchScreen without any animations and add first screen fully equal with LaunchScreen + spinner. Where You can sync your data or do what You need before main flow started